# Why is my Node.js package missing the main file when installed globally?

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install

This feels like an embarrassing question to ask but having recently published a Node package to the NPM registry, I now find it doesn't work.

The issue seems to be that my main file, `./src/index.js`, isn't being included in the global install.

- I know this because when I call the package from the command line it
  runs `./bin/cli.js` in the package as expected, but then throws:

  ```
  Error: Cannot find module '../src/index.js'
  Require stack:
  - /usr/lib/node_modules/diffcraft/bin/cli.js
  ```

  The error even references the line in `./bin/cli.js` where the index
  file is required, so that's definitely where the problem is.
- I also know this because I checked the folder where the module is
  installed globally and while the `bin` folder is there, the `src`
  folder isn't. So the main code for my package just isn't there.

After discovering this, I even patched package.json to ensure that `./src/index.js` was explicitly whitelisted in the `files` array. I hadn't done this before as [NPM guidance](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#files) states that whichever file is listed under `main` is also automatically whitelisted. But even including the file in `files` explicitly hasn't worked.

For reference, I don't have an `.npmignore` file.

I've got a horrible feeling I'm missing something simple and basic... Any ideas why my main file might be being skipped?

The package is [diffcraft](https://www.npmjs.com/package/diffcraft).

Comment: People here could probably help you better if you included a link to the repository so we can see exactly what you have, what's in your package.json, what's in the repository, etc....

Comment: @jfriend00 - Running the `npm repo diffcraft` command will take you to the github repo.

Comment: Thanks @jfriend00 -- thanks for the advice. I've included that now. Was wary before as I'm not trying to promote the package; I just want to solve the problem :-)

Comment: FYI, this doesn't have anything to do with being installed globally.  If you install it locally, the same issue occurs.  The `src` directory is not included in the install.

Comment: What are you trying to do with `"url": "git+https://github.com/guypursey/diffcraft.git"` in the repository section of package.json?  The [NPM doc](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#repository) doesn't show that form anywhere for a github repository.

Comment: Omit the `files` field/key completely from you're projects _package.json_ -  the pathnames to the two files are already defined via `main` and `bin`.

Comment: I see that the archive for your published npm module https://registry.npmjs.org/diffcraft/-/diffcraft-0.1.1.tgz does not contain the desired directories.  So, it appears something went wrong in the publish process.

Comment: @jfriend00 That Git URL was automatically generated... Not sure why it's like that. Do you think it may be causing an issue?

Comment: @RobC Testing this out in conjunction with the answer from @rveerd below, you seem to be right -- I can delete the files array altogether but only if I also take the `./` off the beginning of the value for `main`. It doesn't seem to matter for `bin`. Not sure why...

Comment: @jfriend00 That Git URL format is mentioned in [Git URLs as dependencies part of the package.json documentation](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#git-urls-as-dependencies), but not in the repositories bit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It works if you omit the `./` in front of the files (tested with npm 6.14.4 on Windows):

```
  "files": [
    "bin/cli.js",
    "src/index.js"
  ],
```

This might be a bug in npm.

You can check this without publishing by running `npm pack` and checking the archive file.

Alternative is using an `.npmignore` file.

Comment: But why is the `src` directory not included by default?  You don't have to explicitly name directories for them to be part of the package, right?

Comment: Omitting the `./` from the `main` field and deleting the `files` array altogether seems to have the same effect. For some reason I don't need to the same for the `bin` field; that gets picked up with or without the `./`. I have no idea why but this approach seems to work -- I'll just run a few more tests...

Comment: PS. Upvoted this answer for mention of `npm pack` alone. Thanks for that.

Comment: PPS. Also finding `npm publish --dry-run` useful in that regard.

Comment: That definitely seems to have solved it. I ended up removing the `./` from the pathnames for the `main` and the `bin` files and left `files` in as an empty array (as that seemed more economical than creating `.npmignore` to exclude everything else in my folder). Thanks for the help!

Comment: @jfriend00 If you don't specify `files`, it uses the default, which is `["*"]`, and all files will be included, including `src/index.js`. But because the OP specified `files` the default no longer applies. And only files matching `files` will be included. For some reason `src/index.js` does not match `./src/index.js` and thus is not included.

Comment: @jfriend00 Some files are always included; `bin/cli.js` is not included because it matches `files` but probably because it is specified as the `bin` file. However, the [npm documentation](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#files) states that the `main` file is always included but this does not seems to be the case.